# What "missing satellite" was part of the story of CNN's debut?

Tags: history, communication-satellite

NPR's [Tune In To 'Up All Night' For The Story Of Daniel Schorr And The Birth Of CNN](https://www.npr.org/2020/06/13/865768820/tune-in-to-up-all-night-for-the-story-of-daniel-schorr-and-the-birth-of-cnn) includes the following about the beginnings of [Cable News Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNN)

> On CNN's rocky debut:
>
> There were so many obstacles. **A satellite went missing.** [Avid sailor] Ted went missing at sea. He couldn't necessarily raise the money that was necessary.

**Question:** What "missing satellite" was part of the story of CNN's debut? Was it a communications satellite? Did it really go missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Satcom 3

> In fairly rapid succession, two Japanese communication satellites,
>   Ayame I and II, and the RCA SATCOM III spacecraft failed during the
>   firing sequence of the Apogee Kick Motor (AKM) in such a manner as to
>   suggest a single common casual (sic) failure mode. Individual reviews of
>   these three flights have all focused on the failure of the AKM as the
>   single most probable event leading to the nonsuccess of the mission.

Source [AYAME/PAM-D APOGEE KICK MOTOR NOZZLE FAILURE ANALYSIS](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19820002238.pdf)

> Despite sophisticated tracking systems, the satellite was never
>   located and its fate remains unknown.

Source: [1981 UPI Article](https://www.upi.com/Archives/1981/11/19/The-RCA-Satcom-III-R-commercial-communications-satellite-designed-to/9466374994000/)

Update: see this answer for its actual fate (determined after the UPI article was written): https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44790/6944

> The Cable News Network was intended to be distributed on RCA's new
>   Satcom 3, which was lost on its launch date of December 7, 1979.

Source - [wikipedia "history of cnn"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_CNN_(1980%E2%80%932003)#Early_history_(1980%E2%80%931989))

Source: New York Times [RCA Loses Contact with New Satellite](https://www.nytimes.com/1979/12/11/archives/rca-loses-contact-with-new-satellite-search-for-newest-comsat-began.html)

Comment: Thanks! This has piqued my curiousity, so I've just asked [How could RCA Satcom III have been completely lost? (Or was it?)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44788/12102)